# how do i display a key (only)from a sorted list?

Tags: c#, collections, label, keyvaluepair

I'm trying to determine the proper syntax for displaying a random key on each label.

[image: display random sorted list key on label]

```
//declare random
Random rnd = new Random();

//create the sorted list and add items
SortedList<string,string> sl = new SortedList<string,string>();
sl.Add("PicknPay", "jam");
sl.Add("Spar", "bread");
sl.Add("Checkers", "rice");
sl.Add("Shoprite", "potato");
sl.Add("Cambridge", "spinash");

int Count = 0;
int nValue = rnd.Next(5);
int newindex = 0;
int seekindex;

for (seekindex = 0; seekindex > nValue; seekindex++)
{
    newindex =  rnd.Next(seekindex);
}

lbl1.Text = "";

foreach (var item in sl.Keys) 
{
    lbl1.Text += "," + Convert.ToString(item.IndexOf(item));
}

lbl1.Text = lbl1.Text.TrimStart(',');
```

Comment: Are you trying to choose a unique, random key from your `SortedList` to display in each of the three labels? Your code indicates that you're trying to display all of them, separated by commas, in `lbl1.Text`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this correctly. Do you want to display each `Key` in `sl` in a label of its own?

Comment: In case you want randomly shuffle you sorted list you could use linq order by in your second for each https://stackoverflow.com/a/4262134/3254405

Comment: when the form loads . the three labels are supposed to display a Randomly selected key FROM the sorted list ...for example when form loads label 1 will display "spar" and label 2 display "shopright" ,label3 displays cambridge  but if the form loads again then should pick different keys from the above randomly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be get a randomly ordered list of the keys by calling the `System.Linq` extension method [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) and passing it the value returned from [`Random.Next()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b3ta19y(v=vs.110).aspx), then take the first three items from this shuffled list:

```
SortedList<string, string> sl = new SortedList<string, string>
{
    {"PicknPay", "jam"},
    {"Spar", "bread"},
    {"Checkers", "rice"},
    {"Shoprite", "potato"},
    {"Cambridge", "spinash"}
};

var rnd = new Random();
var shuffledKeys = sl.Keys.OrderBy(key => rnd.Next()).ToList();

lbl1.Text = shuffledKeys[0];
lbl2.Text = shuffledKeys[1];
lbl3.Text = shuffledKeys[2];
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `OrderBy(key => rnd.NextDouble())`. Neat trick, will add to my 'Tips and Tricks', thanks!

Comment: Thank you @Rufus L Thank you, you legend you , you made so simple .. my textbooks are pretty useless they do not explain properly . i humbly request you refer me to a book that can properly teach me what i need to learn.

Comment: One question though, why `NextDouble()` and not `Next()`?

Comment: @MO_Tries I'm afraid I cannot recommend any books at the moment - I mostly learn on the job and online. My suggestion is to keep playing with small projects, ask lots of questions, and you will be successful!

Comment: @Sach `Next()` works too, and it's probably a little more efficient. I'll change the sample.